# Spin another docker container and pod in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have 3 pods in kubernetes each with separate and single docker container. Each docker container has its own express app.

1. Pod 1 => Docker Container A
2. Pod 2 => Docker Container B
3. Pod 3 => Docker Container C

All this 3 pods interacts with each other via NATS streaming server for pub/sub purposes.

Now, I am looking into how to spin up another pod with a single Docker Container D. The context is, Docker Container A will receive codes from client. I need to run the codes and generate the output.

My thought process is, when Container A received the request.

1. Start another pod in kubernetes.
2. Initiate Container D
3. Run the codes and generate output.
4. Return back the output to Container D.
5. Container A sends back the response to user.
6. Stop Container D and its pod.

Please kindly let me know if there is a better way to implement this course of action. I am out of clue on how to starting another pod in kubernetes from a different container and also different pod.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably need the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/) for this; beyond the mechanics of building the original image, you would not use any "Docker" technologies.  Think carefully about the security implications of running untrusted code since it's often possible to make network calls within the cluster (inside your typical security boundary) and you may not want to run some classes of tasks (cryptocurrency miners as a relatively benign one).

Comment: Hmm, not very clear for me but I have been planning to use ingress-controller to make calls between pods within k8s. I am not planning to make directs access between pods via port forwarding.  

Is this the right way?

Comment: Between Pods, you should be able to use an ordinary (ClusterIP-type) [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).  You only need an Ingress object to accept (HTTP) connections from outside the cluster, and port forwarding only for debugging.

Comment: Now it is clear. That is what I am going towards. Sorry that I don't really know much about the jargons properly as I'm relatively new to k8s.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need "job" kinds.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

First, I assume that you need 1 process per 1 jobs.

So,

1. Pod A stamp job as JOB.1
2. Pod A create K8S job with parameter to wait JOB.1 in NATs
3. Pod A send JOB.1 to NATs

Once Job process start. it will pull NATs to get JOB.1 todo. Job should terminate itself once it finish.

However, if I design the service. I prefer create Container D as pool of worker which can scale using HPA based on CPU/memory usage.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you man. This is what I have been looking for and will look into k8s Job concept.